# Why is Ruby's Hash#values faster than Hash#each_value in certain cases?

Tags: ruby, performance, internals

When I apply `each_value` to a hash, it takes significantly longer than when I use `values`, even though `each_value` ostensibly avoids allocating and copying an array.

I wrote a simple comparison:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

some_hash = File.open('with_an.dat') { |f| Marshal.load f }

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report "calling each_value" do
    some_hash.each_value
  end
  x.report "calling values" do
    some_hash.values
  end
  x.compare!
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report "summing each_value" do
    some_hash.each_value.inject &:+
  end
  x.report "summing values" do
    some_hash.values.inject &:+
  end
  x.compare!
end
```

And here were the results:

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
  calling each_value    58.166k i/100ms
      calling values     2.000  i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
  calling each_value      1.312M (±40.7%) i/s -      5.468M
      calling values     29.423  (±10.2%) i/s -    146.000 

Comparison:
  calling each_value:  1312156.6 i/s
      calling values:       29.4 i/s - 44596.28x slower

Calculating -------------------------------------
  summing each_value     1.000  i/100ms
      summing values     1.000  i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
  summing each_value      2.107  (± 0.0%) i/s -     11.000 
      summing values      8.002  (±12.5%) i/s -     40.000 

Comparison:
      summing values:        8.0 i/s
  summing each_value:        2.1 i/s - 3.80x slower
```

As expected, just calling each of the methods, `each_value` was much faster, since it only has to create an `Enumerator`, and doesn't actually traverse the hash table.  Meanwhile, `values` has to copy the entire array.

Yet, when I add the values up, it appears that the `each_value` approach is 3x *slower* than the `values` approach.  Why would that be?

Comment: The overhead of yielding each individual value?

Comment: `inject(:+)` will do, and should be faster than `inject(&:+)`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What do you mean? Both methods are yielding individual values.

Comment: @mudasobwa: ah, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating `Hash` is slower, than iterating `Array`:

```
 ▶ Benchmark.bm do |x|
 ▷   x.report do
 ▷     n.times do
 ▷       {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}.inject(1) { |memo, (_, v)| memo * v }
 ▷     end
 ▷   end
 ▷   x.report do
 ▷     n.times do
 ▷       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].inject(1) { |memo, v| memo * v }
 ▷     end
 ▷   end
 ▷ end

 #⇒      user     system      total        real
 #⇒  0.700000   0.010000   0.710000 (  0.712821)
 #⇒  0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.349040)
```

By calling `each_value` one in fact iterates the original `Hash` instance, while by calling `values.each` the iteration is being done on the `Array` instance (`values`.)

To answer the question “why is that” one should probably take a look at [`rb_hash_foreach`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/hash.c#226) and `rb_array_foreach` native implementation for different ruby versions.

Comment: Right, but Hash#values must iterate over the hash in order to generate the array result, so its cost would be that of generating the array (thereby iterating over the hash) plus iterating over the array.

Comment: I am not sure, but I kinda saw that hash is stored in the memory as an array with keys pointing to this array’s elements memory addresses.

Comment: The latter does not explain why we can’t use the fast iterator for `each_value` when needed. I admire the question: it is rather great and probably should be addressed to Matz (stated as “why we can’t use the fastest iterator always?”.)

Comment: There is definitely room for improvement in Ruby then, but the answer is right. It is faster to iterate an Array than a Hash and apparently having to get array of values (source [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-values)) does not offset the performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the reason is optimization of [Hash#values](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/hash.c#1677) method implementation.

In your 1st benchmark you are comparing apples (enumerator creation) with oranges (array creation). It is to be expected, building whole array is more costly then producing a single generator with access to final values requiring additional calls.

If you write equivalent examples, results would be different:

```
  some_hash =  ('aa'..'zz').each_with_index.to_h

  Benchmark.ips do |x|
    x.report "array from map" do
      some_hash.map &:last
    end
    x.report "array from each_value" do
      some_hash.each_value.to_a
    end
    x.report "array from values" do
      some_hash.values
    end
    x.compare!
  end

  Comparison:
        array from values:   171143.8 i/s
    array from each_value:    15195.8 i/s - 11.26x slower
           array from map:     6040.9 i/s - 28.33x slower
```

Nothing too surprising, just be aware this is an implementation specific detail you shouldn't rely on in most cases. Algorithmical complexity is what counts.

Comment: > Algorithmical complexity is what counts.

True, but the point of the question was Ruby internals, not algorithm design.

Comment: @bcc32 So did satisfied the answer your curiosity ? `Hash#values` is *specialized* method, expected to perform better then *generic* enumerator and fetching its values subsequently. `Enumerable#inject` can't magically backward change how the target object is created, unless by some sophisticated optimizer not present in any Ruby implementation AFAIK. Btw. in JRuby 9.0.5.0 *"summing each_value"* example is only 1.1x slower.

Comment: The statement “`Hash#values` is _specialized_ method” is kinda bad answer on the question “what is _specialized_ in `Hash#values` method” :)

Comment: @mudasobwa Huh ? I see no cited question from the OP. By *specialized* was meant creation of a container and storing all results in one step/call, which can be optimized more straightforward then producing a generator, from which results are yielded subsequently.